# How can i do with jetpack compose dropdown list with numbers

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

How can I make a component like in the image that is a drop-down list of numbers with jetpack compose? Is there no component similar to the HTML select?

[dropdown list with numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNJXT.png)

```
fun DropDownListSeries(numero: (Int) -> Unit, size: Int) {
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
    ) {
        val options = getNumbersList(size).map { it }
        var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        var selectedOptionText by remember { mutableStateOf(options[0].toString()) }

        ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
            expanded = expanded,
            onExpandedChange = { expanded = !expanded }
        ) {
            OutlinedTextFieldBackground(Color.White) {
                OutlinedTextField(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .menuAnchor()
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    readOnly = true,
                    value = selectedOptionText,
                    onValueChange = {},
                    leadingIcon = {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_series),
                            contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.lib_series),
                            tint = colorResource(id = R.color.background_tool_bar)
                        )
                    },
                    trailingIcon = { ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded) },
                    colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors(
                        unfocusedContainerColor = Color.White,
                        focusedContainerColor = Color.White
                    )
                )
            }
            ExposedDropdownMenu(
                expanded = expanded,
                onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
            ) {
                options.forEach { selectionOption ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        text = { Text(selectionOption.toString()) },
                        onClick = {
                            selectedOptionText = selectionOption.toString()
                            numero(selectionOption)
                            expanded = false
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You already answered the question yourself: You can use an `ExposedDropdownMenuBox` to achieve a dropdown like select in HTML.